# why some tikz pics scale and some do not?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzscale

Was trying scale option to tikzpicture and found that on some pics it works and on some it does not.  I do not know why.

Here is MWE

[image]

Here is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle,   draw=red,  text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm]

\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]    
    \node [block, minimum width=2in] at (0,0) (A) {text};
    \node [block, below =of A] (B) {more test};
    \draw[->] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

And

\noindent\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]    
    \node [block, minimum width=2in] at (0,0) (A) {text};
    \node [block, below =of A] (B) {more test};
    \draw[->] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\noindent\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\noindent\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

Why it works in the second one but not the first? I have thought that the whole pic will scale always.

TL 2023

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to scale nodes, you need to also give the `transform shape` option (same is true for rotation, iirc):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,fit}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle,   draw=red,  text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=1cm]

\begin{document}
\noindent\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3, transform shape]    
    \node [block, minimum width=2in] at (0,0) (A) {text};
    \node [block, below =of A] (B) {more test};
    \draw[->] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

And

\noindent\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]    
    \node [block, minimum width=2in] at (0,0) (A) {text};
    \node [block, below =of A] (B) {more test};
    \draw[->] (A)--(B);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\noindent\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\noindent\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```